# What does this operator (=~) in Cypher mean?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I can't find this operator (`=~`) in [Neo4j docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-operators.html), but they are using it in [this example](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.7/cypher-introduction.html):

```
MATCH (user)-[:friend]->(follower)
WHERE user.name IN ['Joe', 'John', 'Sara', 'Maria', 'Steve'] AND follower.name =~ 'S.*'
RETURN user, follower.name
```

Any idea of what it means?

Comment: check in here - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-parameters-java.html under regular expressions. In your example it would be followers whose name attribute starts with **S**

Comment: @DaveBennett So what's the meaning? Equal to the specified regular expression?

Comment: Yes, that is it exactly. The =~ operator will tell neo4j to evaluate the string to the right as a regular expression. This ref is better... http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-where.html#_regular_expressions

Comment: @DaveBennett can I suggest adding your answer as an answer (and Manolo accepting it) so others can easily find the answer to this question?  thanks!

Comment: @DaveBennett weird, the answer just took a while to show up. It's there now! and posted long before my comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `=~` operator will tell neo4j to evaluate the string to the right as a regular expression.  This ref is better...

http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#query-where-regex